# how to get href value in <a> tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, class

Inside the `html` source code, there's an `<a>` tag with an `href` attribute, I want to get whatever it has after the second slash after `individuals` which in this case is `22284494`.
The exact tag is:

`<a href="/individuals/22284494" class="i-photo">`

How do I do that using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would target the anchor, get the attribute, split on `/` and get the last part

```
var numb = $('a.i-photo').attr('href').split('/').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
$(".i-photo").attr("href").split("/")[2]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[1]` instead?

Comment: @D4V No, because there are two slashes. [0] is "", [1] is "individuals", [2] is "22284494".

Comment: Right, so `[0]` outputs nothing then? *Edit*: okay :)